# XAML Transparency through multiple layers

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Rectangle with an overlapping Ellipse. I would like the Ellipse to have a border, which basically "cuts out" the Rectangle and shows the background that's beneath both of the objects. Is there any way to do that?
I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Here are my objects:

```xaml
<Canvas Background="LightGray"/> <!-- this Canvas will show an image -->
<Rectangle Fill="#590ABAB5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="70"/>
<Ellipse Width="120" Height="120" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

And this is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Comment: What are you working in? WPF, WP, SL, etc? Do you have OpacityMask available?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to tag that. I'm working with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090206/chris-w) says in  the comments, you can use the [`OpacityMask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [`GeometryDrawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrydrawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="https://c.s-microsoft.com/fr-fr/CMSImages/ltr_mobile_still.png?version=4863852c-ce59-fe13-2d00-11a37dfdc665" />
    </Grid.Background>

    <local:GeometryBorder CircleSize="140"
                          Background="#590ABAB5"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          Height="70"/>

    <Ellipse Width="120"
             Height="120"
             Fill="Red"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
</Grid>
```

Using a custom border control:

```
public class GeometryBorder : Border
{
    #region CircleSize

    public double CircleSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CircleSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CircleSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CircleSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CircleSize", typeof(double), typeof(GeometryBorder), new PropertyMetadata(1.0, OnCircleSizeChanged));

    private static void OnCircleSizeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = d as GeometryBorder;
        border.ApplyOpacityMask();
    }

    #endregion

    public GeometryBorder()
    {
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    protected void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplyOpacityMask();
    }

    protected void ApplyOpacityMask()
    {
        if (ActualWidth > 0 && ActualHeight > 0)
        {
            var rectangle = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
            var ellipse = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(ActualWidth / 2.0, 0), CircleSize / 2.0, CircleSize / 2.0);
            var geometry = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, rectangle, ellipse);
            var drawing = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, new Pen(), geometry);
            var brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
            OpacityMask = brush;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

That is aero effect in WPF based on visualbrush and blur effect, transparent item (a Rectangle in this case) is defined this way:

```
<Rectangle>  
    <Rectangle.Effect>  
        <BlurEffect Radius="{DynamicResource BlurRadius}"/>  
    </Rectangle.Effect>  
    <Rectangle.Fill>  
        <VisualBrush  ViewboxUnits="Absolute"  Viewbox="{Binding RenderTransform.Children[3],  Converter={StaticResource TranslateTransformToRectViewboxVisualBrushConverter},  
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},  
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
        AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"  
    Visual="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundContainer}" Stretch="None">  
            <VisualBrush.Transform>  
                <TranslateTransform X="0" />  
            </VisualBrush.Transform>  
        </VisualBrush>  
    </Rectangle.Fill>  
</Rectangle>
```

Here is a screen

[image]

Comment: Your sample do not run as is (missing resources, DataContext, etc.) Besides, are you sure that it answers the question (changing the opacity of a part of a rectangle)?

Comment: Ok, I will check it again.